# SQL Server Sub query in select insert

Tags: sql, sql-insert, sql-server-2014

Any suggestions on getting this to work? syntactically it is correct, and the individual sub-queries return a single result, however when combined the sub-queries do not return results to the insert statement. Essentially i am trying to insert these records into the table if they do not exist in the view.

```
INSERT INTO PRG_T_BLK_MDL (BLK_ID, MDL_ID, GW, VE)
    OUTPUT @@ROWCOUNT AS RC
    SELECT (SELECT ID FROM PRG_T_BLK WHERE NAME=1),
            (SELECT ID FROM PRG_T_MDL WHERE NAME='A'), 3500, 'AX'
    FROM PRG_V_BLK_MDL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PRG_V_BLK_MDL WHERE BLK=1 AND MDL='A' AND VER='AX')
```

Comment: Have you tried switching this from NOT EXISTS to EXCEPT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that the `OUTPUT` clause works (I haven't used it with `@@ROWCOUNT`, but it seems ok).

You don't need a `FROM` clause -- at least not with the entire table.  I might suggest:

```
INSERT INTO PRG_T_BLK_MDL (BLK_ID, MDL_ID, GW, VE)
    OUTPUT @@ROWCOUNT AS RC
    SELECT (SELECT ID FROM PRG_T_BLK WHERE NAME = t.BLK),
            (SELECT ID FROM PRG_T_MDL WHERE NAME = t.MDL), 3500, t.ver
    FROM (SELECT 1 as BLK, 'A' as MDL, 'AX' as ver) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM PRG_V_BLK_MDL v
                      WHERE v.BLK = t.BLK AND v.MDL = t.MDL AND v.ver = t.ver);
```

Comment: That did it, Thanks!